# Flutter: Use an mark operator in check state

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an array of items. If one is empty I want to display text "You have not any tasks yet" but if there's added one I want to display text "Congrats for add first task" but there's an error that value have to be bool type.
[Here's screen of my editor with code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84oSD.png)

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<String> items = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: items
        ? Text("Congrats, you have one")
        : Text("You haven't any tasks yet"),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in properties [`isEmpty`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Iterable/isEmpty.html) and [`isNotEmpty`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Iterable/isNotEmpty.html) to check an `Iterable` (in your case, a `List`) or a `String`:

```dart
child: items.isNotEmpty
        ? Text("Congrats, you have one")
        : Text("You haven't any tasks yet"),
```

Answer (score 0):

`items` is not a condition, it is the list.

What you want is: `items.isEmpty`

```
child: items.isEmpty
 ? Text('empty') 
 : Text('something');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options

1. methods like `isEmpty` | `isNotEmpty`

```
child: items.isEmpty
 ? Text('empty') 
 : Text('something');
```

2. check in string way

```
child: items.toString() == '[]' ? Text('empty'): Text('good to go'),
```